# Keyboard navigation between div`s CSS transition issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working at a carousel like CSS transition between div`s that will be used as the header of a mouse-less application. The transition gives the feel of a "flow" between two neighboring elements.
You can see here the work I've done until now: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOWVGR. The focus of the elements is controlled using the 'a' key for left and the 's' key for right.

I almost made it work using a gradient and a background position transition, except I can't figure out how to code the effect when moving towards one direction only, case in which the previous elements "background" goes back to the initial background position instead of "following" the newly selected div`s background position.

```
.left, .right {
    background-size: 202% 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%,green 50%);
    -webkit-transition: background-position .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-position .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-position .3s ease-in-out;
}

.left:focus {
    background-position: 100% 0;
}

.right:focus {
    background-position: -100% 0;
}
```

The desired effect is "working" only in one case, if you press right-left (s - a) or left-right (a - s) in the demo I created. I also added the following image to make it more easy to understand the desired effect.
[Desired flow of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRVfA.png)

Any ideas will be very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a problem with the end element, which is not returning to the first element and vice versa? or do you have a problem with the transition, when you click more than one time on one direction?

Comment: Hi thomas, I have a problem with the transition of the "unfocusing" element when I click more than one time twords a direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create the animation mostly using javascript. The code adds the following "animatedBg" CSS class to the current and previous elements and modifies the background position of both elements achieving this way the animations I asked for.

I now need to find a way of maintaining the fluency of the animation when holding a direction button down.

The bellow snippet can be tested using the left - right arrows.

```js
document.getElementById("1").focus();
var current = 0;
var cls = "right";

var positions = [-100, "x", "x", "x" , "x"];
updateItems();
addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        if (current === 0) {
            return;
        }
        current--;

        var newPositions = ["x", "x", "x", "x" , "x"];;
        if (cls === "left") {
            newPositions[current] = 100;
        } else {
            if (positions[current] !== 0) {
                newPositions[current] = -100;
            } else {
                newPositions[current] = 100;
            }
        }
        newPositions[current + 1] = positions[current + 1] + 100;
        cls = "left";
        positions = newPositions;

    }
    if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        if (current === 4) {
            return;
        }
        current++;
        var newPositions = ["x", "x", "x", "x" , "x"];
        if (cls === "right") {
            newPositions[current] = -100;
        } else {
            if (positions[current] !== 0) {
                newPositions[current] = 100;
            } else {
                newPositions[current] = -100;
            }
        }
        newPositions[current - 1] = positions[current - 1] - 100;
        cls = "right";
        positions = newPositions;
    }
    updateItems();
});

function updateItems() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById("" + i);

        if(positions[i] === "x") {
            if (element.classList.contains("animatedBg")){
                element.classList.remove("animatedBg");
            }
            element.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        }
        if (positions[i] !== "x") {
            if(!element.classList.contains("animatedBg")){
                element.classList.add("animatedBg");
            }
            element.style.backgroundPosition = positions[i] + "% 0";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body { 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
    height: 140px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 60px 0px 20px;
}

.item a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    outline: 0px;
}

.animatedBg {
  background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 51%,green 50%);
    -webkit-transition: background-position .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-position .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-position .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="item">
  <a id="0" class="animatedBg" href="/1" tabindex="-1">1</a>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <a id="1" class="" href="/2" tabindex="-1">22</a>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <a id="2" class="" href="/3" tabindex="-1">333</a>
 </div>
  <div class="item">
  <a id="3" class="" href="/4" tabindex="-1">4444</a>
 </div>
  <div class="item">
  <a id="4" class="" href="/3" tabindex="-1">55555</a>
 </div>
</div>
```